How to watch the changeroute in a server component in next.js 14
I need to listen the change route in the RootLayout of a next.js project v14. Basically I have a Navbar that I would like to keep it in the RootLayout as a server component. Is there a way to listen the change of the route inside? I need it in order to change the style of the Navbar while I am on a determinate route.
I have this RootLayout:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { lng },
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { lng: string };
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang={lng} dir={dir(lng)}>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar locale={lng}>{children}</Navbar>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

CanI do that here? Or should I just have to turn the Navbar into a client component? I would avoid this since I would need to put it in every page of my app. It would also probably flicker when I will change the route.
